# How to join data from two collections in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'am developing some application on MEAN.js boilerplate and I've got one problem which I'm not able to solve by myself :(
I've got a following database scheme:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    profession: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Profession'
    },
    game: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Game'
    }
};

var ProfessionSchema = new Schema({
    assignedTaskCategories: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'TaskCategory'
    }]
});

var TaskCategorySchema = new Schema({
    professions: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Profession'
    }],
    assignedToGame: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Game'
    }
});

var TaskSchema = new Schema({
    game: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Game'
    },
    inCategories: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'TaskCategory'
    }]
});
```

Now I would like to get all Tasks, which have got some element in `inCategories` same as User's profession taskCategories array.
I've tried this, but it returns nothing

```
Profession.find({ _id: req.user.profession }).exec(function(err, userCategories) {
        if(err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            Task.find({ game: req.user.game, inCategories: userCategories.assignedTaskCategories}).exec(function(err, tasks) {
                if(err) {
                    return res.status(400).sed({
                        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                    });
                } else {
                    res.json(tasks);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Could anyone help me with this? :) If my approach is bad, please tell me the right way how can I solve it :)

### EDIT

We cannot use $setEquals, because the array are not same, consider following example:

Profession **programmer** is able to solve following task categories:
**Programming, Presentation, Wash dishes**

Profession **secretary** is able to solve following task categories:
**Presentation, Wash dishes**

Then we will create a task, which is assigned to category: **Wash dishes**, so the professions `assignedCategories` arrays are bigger, not equal to task's `inCategories` array.

Comment: But in your original question you mention _Now I would like to get all Tasks, which have got same inCategories_?? How does that not translate to the same arrays? Can you be a bit more specific on what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: sorry, my mistake .. my english is not very well ... but I think I've got a solution: `Task.find({ game: req.user.game, inCategories: { $in: profession[0].assignedTaskCategories }})`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** where you employ the [**`$setEquals`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setEquals/#exp._S_setEquals) operator to compare the arrays. In the following pipeline, the operator determines if the Tasks' `inCategories` array and the `assignedTaskCategories` array contain the same elements:

```
Profession.find({ _id: req.user.profession }).exec(function(err, userCategories) {
    if(err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    } else {
        var pipeline = [
            {
                "$match": { "game": req.user.game }
            },
            {
                "$project": { 
                    "game": 1, 
                    "inCategories": 1, 
                    "sameElements": { 
                        "$setEquals": [ "$inCategories", userCategories[0].assignedTaskCategories ] 
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "$match": { "sameElements": true }
            }
        ];
        Task.aggregate(pipeline)
            .exec(function (err, tasks){
                if(err) {
                    return res.status(400).sed({
                        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                    });
                } else {
                    res.json(tasks);
                }
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've tried your code, but it doesn't work :( If I'll tried to comment `$project` code block, it will return all tasks from matched game (as expected). But now it returns empty array, with no results :(

Comment: Maybe the problem is this?
`console.log(userCategories[0].assignedTaskCategories)` output:
`["55365075f9e809c8285d99a3","5550a9604b24bcdc1b88cc76"]`
`console.log(tasks[0].inCategories` output:
`[ 5550a9604b24bcdc1b88cc76 ]`
The second array has got id without quotes

Comment: @user3216673 Clearly the arrays returned do not have the same elements hence the new field `sameElements` has false a false value since the `$setEquals` operator is comparing the array `[ 5550a9604b24bcdc1b88cc76 ]` with `["55365075f9e809c8285d99a3","5550a9604b24bcdc1b88cc76"]`

Comment: After another 2 hours I am completely lost, because ...
1) `console.log(tasks[0].inCategories);` always returns an array with id without quotes || 2) `console.log(profession[0])` returns a profession object with atribute assignedTaskCategories, where's an aray with ids without quotes || 3) `console.log(profession[0].assignedTaskCategories);` returns array with ids in quotes ...damn what's wrong?!