# IDs in quotes when using MongoDB $setEquals

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've got a problem with quoted IDs in referenced array. When I try this:

```
Task.find({ game: req.user.game }).exec(function(err, task) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(task[0].inCategories);
    }
});
```

it writes an array of IDs in quotes to node.js console (`["5550a9604b24bcdc1b88cc76", "5551213c35d0516807b2cd99"]`). But then I'm trying to return Task for a logged in user (look at the comments next to `console.log` commands):

```
Profession.find({ _id: req.user.profession }).exec(function(err, profession) {
    if(err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    } else {
        console.log(profession[0].assignedTaskCategories); // output: array with quoted IDs
        var pipeline = [
            {
                '$match': { 'game': req.user.game,  }
            },
            {
                '$project': { 
                    'title': 1,
                    'game': 1, 
                    'inCategories': 1, 
                    'sameElements': { 
                        '$setEquals': [ '$inCategories', profession[0].assignedTaskCategories ] 
                    }
                }
            }
        ];
        Task.aggregate(pipeline).exec(function (err, tasks){
            if(err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            } else {
                console.log(tasks[0].inCategories); //array with IDs without quotes
                res.json(tasks);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Value of `sameElements` is false, because `$setEquals` compares arrays, one with quoted IDs, one without quotes and I don't know why it's happening???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try casting the `assignedTaskCategories` elements to ObjectIds first then do the comparison:

```
console.log(profession[0].assignedTaskCategories); // output: array with quoted IDs
var assignedTaskCategories = profession[0].assignedTaskCategories.map(function( category ) {
    return mongoose.Types.ObjectId(category);
});
var pipeline = [
    {
        '$match': { 'game': req.user.game,  }
    },
    {
        '$project': { 
            'title': 1,
            'game': 1, 
            'inCategories': 1, 
            'sameElements': { 
                '$setEquals': [ '$inCategories', assignedTaskCategories ] 
            }
        }
    }
];
Task.aggregate(pipeline).exec(function (err, tasks){
    if(err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    } else {
        console.log(tasks[0].inCategories); //array with IDs without quotes
        console.log(tasks[0].sameElements); //true or false
        res.json(tasks);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, now both arrays have IDs without quotes, but sameElements is false :( `[ 55362abef762ff2422366854,
  5550a9604b24bcdc1b88cc76,
  5551213c35d0516807b2cd99 ]
[ 5550a9604b24bcdc1b88cc76, 5551213c35d0516807b2cd99 ]`

Comment: @user3216673 Are the arrays the same? Can you do some logging on both arrays just before you apply the aggregation pipeline and see whether they are equal or not. Note [**`$setQuals`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setEquals/) compares two or more arrays and returns true if they have the same distinct elements and false otherwise.

Comment: @user3216673 Those are not the same that's why it's returning false; `[ 55362abef762ff2422366854, 5550a9604b24bcdc1b88cc76, 5551213c35d0516807b2cd99 ]` is not equal to `[ 5550a9604b24bcdc1b88cc76, 5551213c35d0516807b2cd99 ]` because there is an extra ID element `55362abef762ff2422366854` which is not in the other array.

Comment: Ok, your answer with IDs is correct, but my previous question is still not solved [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169902/how-to-join-data-from-two-colections-in-mongodb/)

Comment: @user3216673 Use the same concept as above; you need to cast the ID strings to ObjectIds first. I will update the other answer to reflect this but the casting should solve it.

Comment: It will not solve it, it's the same example, Profession is able to solve more taskCategories, while task is assigned to less taskCategories.